# Google Play Games Integration Doing Nothing Except a Pop-up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am using **Unity 2020.2** and **Google Play Services Plugin Version 0.10.11 (latest)**
When Ever I Build and run the app on Android Device,  It just shows a Simple Pop-up saying - *"Connecting To Google Play Games"* and then nothing happens at all. Neither it connects to Play Games, nor it shows any error...
**I tried checking all things in Play Console and Developer Console but everything seems fine, tried many solutions but nothing works.** Please Help, I am really Tired..
Script Used -->

```cs
void Start()
        {
            Authenticate(); 
        }

public void Authenticate()
        {
            try {
                Debug.Log("Starting");
                PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
                Debug.Log("config made");
    
                PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
                Debug.Log("Activated Instance");
                PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
                Debug.Log("Activated Platform");
                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate((bool success) =>
                {
                    Debug.Log("Inside Authentication, Success = "+success);
                    if (success)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Authenticated");
    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Failed");
                    }
                }
                );
    
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error :---");
                Debug.Log(e);
            }
        }
```

Here is the Log : (adb logcat):

```
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : Starting
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : GPGSManager:Authenticate()
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
11-02 14:40:42.499 19664 19679 I Unity   :
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : config made
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : GPGSManager:Authenticate()
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
11-02 14:40:42.500 19664 19679 I Unity   :
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : Activated Instance
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : GPGSManager:Authenticate()
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
11-02 14:40:42.501 19664 19679 I Unity   :
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : Activated Platform
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : GPGSManager:Authenticate()
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
11-02 14:40:42.502 19664 19679 I Unity   :
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : Starting Auth with token client.
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient:Authenticate(Boolean, Action`1)
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : GPGSManager:Authenticate()
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
11-02 14:40:42.503 19664 19679 I Unity   :
11-02 14:40:42.504 19664 19679 W Unity   : !!! [Play Games Plugin 0.10.11] 11-02-20 14:40:42 +05:30 WARNING: PlayGamesPlatform already initialized. Ignoring this call.
11-02 14:40:42.504 19664 19679 W Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:42.504 19664 19679 W Unity   : System.Action:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:42.504 19664 19679 W Unity   : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
11-02 14:40:42.504 19664 19679 W Unity   :
11-02 14:40:42.698 19664 19679 W Unity   : Internal: JobTempAlloc has allocations that are more than 4 frames old - this is not allowed and likely a leak
11-02 14:40:42.698 19664 19679 W Unity   :
11-02 14:40:42.885 19664 19664 I Unity   : windowFocusChanged: false
11-02 14:40:42.885 19664 19664 I Unity   : onPause
11-02 14:40:42.919 19664 19679 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.019150 / 0.00s ; BMA255 Accelerometer/Temperature/Double-tap / BOSCH
11-02 14:40:48.213 19664 19664 I Unity   : windowFocusChanged: true
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : Returning an error code.
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : GooglePlayGames.Android.<>c__DisplayClass18_0:<Authenticate>b__0(Int32)
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy:Invoke(String, Object[])
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   : UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper:InvokeJavaProxyMethod(AndroidJavaProxy, IntPtr, IntPtr)
11-02 14:40:48.244 19664 19664 I Unity   :
11-02 14:40:48.247 19664 19664 I Unity   : onResume
11-02 14:40:48.257 19664 19679 D Unity   : Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.019150 / 0.00s ; BMA255 Accelerometer/Temperature/Double-tap / BOSCH
11-02 14:40:48.280 19664 19679 D Unity   : Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : Inside Authentication, Success = False
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : GPGSManager:<Authenticate>b__5_0(Boolean)
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action`2:Invoke(T1, T2)
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : GooglePlayGames.<>c__DisplayClass33_0:<Authenticate>b__0(SignInStatus)11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
11-02 14:40:48.284 19664 19679 I Unity   :
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : Failed
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : GPGSManager:<Authenticate>b__5_0(Boolean)
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action`2:Invoke(T1, T2)
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : GooglePlayGames.<>c__DisplayClass33_0:<Authenticate>b__0(SignInStatus)11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : System.Action:Invoke()
11-02 14:40:48.286 19664 19679 I Unity   : GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
```

[This is what is shows Ingame on Android device](https://answers.unity.com/storage/attachments/170273-screenshot-2020-11-01-21-38-32-820.jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved It :
**I found that the SHA Key provided to me by Google was different from the SHA key from my Keystore.** *(Probably the change signing information after upload)*.

I just added Login Credentials For Both the SHA Keys and it worked.